# 2D Array, Index out of range C#

Tags: c#, labview

For school we have to make a box filter in LabVIEW. Instead of using LabVIEW I choose to use .Net in LabVIEW by creating a DLL. I have done that and the result is an IndexOutOfRange exeption.

My LabVIEW:

[image]

My C# class:

```
public class Filtor
{
    public Int16[,] OrImage { private set; get; }
    public Int16[,] NewImage { private set; get; }
    public int[,] Kernel { private set; get; }
    public int Row { private set; get; }
    public int Column { private set; get; }
    public int RowK { private set; get; }
    public int ColumnK { private set; get; }
    public int N { private set; get; }
    private int Offset;

    public Filtor()
    {
        OrImage = new Int16[0, 0];
        NewImage = OrImage;
        Kernel = new int[0, 0];
        Row = 0;
        Column = 0;
        RowK = 0;
        ColumnK = 0;

        switch (RowK * ColumnK)
        {
            case 9:
                Offset = 1;
                break;

            case 25:
                Offset = 2;
                break;

            case 49:
                Offset = 3;
                break;

            case 81:
                Offset = 4;
                break;

            default:
                Offset = 0;
                break;
        }
    }

    public Filtor(Int16[,] A, int[,] B)
    {
        OrImage = A;
        Kernel = B;
        NewImage = OrImage;
        Row = A.GetLength(0);
        Column = A.GetLength(1);
        RowK = B.GetLength(0);
        ColumnK = B.GetLength(1);

        switch (RowK * ColumnK)
        {
            case 9:
                Offset = 1;
                break;

            case 25:
                Offset = 2;
                break;

            case 49:
                Offset = 3;
                break;

            case 81:
                Offset = 4;
                break;

            default:
                Offset = 0;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void kernelFiltor(int n)
    {
        N = (n > 0) ? n : 1;

        int i, j, k, l, M = 0;

        for (i = Offset; i < (Row - Offset); i++)
        {
            for (j = Offset; j < (Column - Offset); j++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < RowK; k++)
                {
                    for (l = 0; l < ColumnK; l++)
                    {
                        M = M + OrImage[(i + k), (j + l)] * Kernel[k, l];
                    }
                }

                if (((1 / N) * (M / (RowK * ColumnK))) <= 0)
                {
                    NewImage[i, j] = 0;
                }
                else if(((1 / N) * (M / (RowK * ColumnK))) >= 255)
                {
                    NewImage[i, j] = 255;
                }
                else
                {
                    NewImage[i, j] =Convert.ToInt16((1 / N) * (M / (RowK * ColumnK)));
                }
                M = 0;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Can someone, anyone point out ware the error is?

It could be a mistake, a problem with LabVIEW to C# or the other way around.

Small update:

I have the code running in LabVIEW but its not very nice code:

[image]

out of the help I got we can conclude that the problem happens at:

```
for (k = 0; k < RowK; k++)
            {
                for (l = 0; l < ColumnK; l++)
                {
                    M = M + OrImage[(i + k), (j + l)] * Kernel[k, l];
                }
            }
```

when the first 2D array is at the **END**, the second 2D array is moving out of boundary's, what result in a IndexOutOfRange exception. how can i lock the second array **B**, from exiting the boundary's of the first array **A**.

Comment: Tell us where in that code you get “index out of range”.

Comment: that's part of the challenge, LabView doesn't show where it goes wrong, but i know it happens in _kernelFiltor(int n)_  ;)

Comment: Isn't it the code you have written?

Comment: LabVIEW is indeed telling you that the error happens in the .NET class. The way you have approached your school assignment is similar to someone who takes a German class, and upon the first verbal question asks 'Sprechen Sie Englisch?'

Comment: im Dutch and i know my Englisch is a bit rubbish, :)

Comment: Instead of posting images directly, in your block diagram, select your code and then use the menu item "Edit >> Create VI Snippet from Selection". This will create a .PNG file that has embedded info that will allow StackOverflow readers to drag your PNG directly onto a block diagram and instantiate your code. Makes it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Using the class you have defined above and by calling it using the following code:

```
var A = new Int16[1, 1];
A[0, 0] = Int16.MaxValue;

var B = new Int32[2, 1];
B[0, 0] = Int32.MaxValue;
B[1, 0] = Int32.MaxValue;

var f = new Filtor(A, B);
f.kernelFiltor(123);
```

You will be able to see that the code breaks on the following lines in your class:

```
for (k = 0; k < RowK; k++)
{
    for (l = 0; l < ColomK; l++)
    {
        M = M + OrImage[(i + k), (j + l)] * Kernel[k, l];
    }
}
```

More precisely on the following statement:

```
OrImage[(i + k), (j + l)]
```

It appears to be occurring when the `Filtor` class is being instantiated using a lengthier array for `B` than for `A`.

Unfortunately I cannot help you further with this problem as I do not get a clear picture of what you are trying to accomplish. However, now you know where the issue might reside.

Comment: tank you for the analysis it helps. i got it working in Labview and il look like bullSh*T

Comment: I agree it looks pretty bad in LV... but that's pretty much your own fault... that diagram is a mess. Move the 2342423 constant right so it isn't crossing stuff, fix the whitespace in the formula box, put the formula box parameters in a reasonable order, etc. You could do a lot to make this cleaner code. I'd also be curious to see a solution that doesn't involve the Formula Box at all. It would be a fair amount of work to translate the C text into dataflow notation, but sometimes algorithms like these simplify down when you do that (not always, sometimes).